# Creating a Radio-style Preference

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm trying to create a Radio-style `Preference` where the user can click an option which is then assigned as the new value of the `Preference`:

[image]

however when I click one option is selects all 3 options:

[image]

Here is my layout:

preferences.xml

```
<Preference
    android:layout="@layout/preference_gender"
    android:key="seeking"
    android:title="Seeking"/>
```

preference_gender.xml

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/seeking"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorIcons"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/male"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/male"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/female"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/settings_textSize"
        android:text="Male"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/settings_gender"
        android:padding="@dimen/settings_box_selection_padding"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/button_horizontal_padding"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/button_horizontal_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/female"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/male"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/both"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/settings_textSize"
        android:text="Female"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/settings_box_selection_padding"
        android:background="@drawable/settings_gender"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/button_horizontal_padding"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/button_horizontal_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/female"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/both"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/settings_textSize"
        android:text="Both"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/settings_box_selection_padding"
        android:background="@drawable/settings_gender"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/button_horizontal_padding"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/button_horizontal_padding"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

So I want to be able to click a textview and then get the value of that in `Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener`.

Any idea how?

EDIT:

```
class PreferencesFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), View.OnClickListener {   

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val genderPreference: Preference = findPreference("seeking")!!
    val parentView = listView.getChildAt(genderPreference.order)
    val childView = parentView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.male) // NullPointerException
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "clicked") // doesn't log
        when (v?.id){
            R.id.male -> Log.d(TAG, "male")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because all three buttons are under one preference item, when you set an `OnPreferenceClickListener`, it selects the entire preference with the layout you included as a whole.

So, instead of setting an `OnPreferenceClickListener` you should try getting the parent view and setting the click listeners on these `TextView`s individually and from there update the preference's value.

**Or you can just set the `onClick` attributes of each `TextView` in the layout xml file to your desired functions.**

To get the View of this preference, you can use something like

```
View preferenceView = getListView().getChildAt(preference.getOrder());
```

Or, use the getView method and supply both parameters with null:

```
View preferenceView = preference.getView(null, null);
```

---

If you are using the AndroidX library for preference, then there's no `getView` method, so the only option would be creating a custom Preference class and deal with the views there:

```
public class CustomPreference extends Preference {
    public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindView(View rootView) {
        super.onBindView(rootView);

        View myView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.myViewId);
        // get your textViews from myView
        TextView maleText = myView.findViewById(R.id.male);
        ...
    }
}
```

Then use it in your preference.xml like this:

```
<your.package.CustomPreference
    android:key="your_key"
    android:layout="@layout/your_layout" />
```

Comment: I used `inflate()` however the `onClick` doesn't fire. Any idea why? I've updated my code above.

Comment: I'm actually not sure if the inflate method would work since it essentially inflates the view twice, did you try the first method?

Comment: Just did and I get a null pointer on the `TextView` - I've updated my code above if you want to see

Comment: How about just try the plain `getView` method? see my update

Comment: `Preference` does not have a `getView()` method?

Comment: Are you using the AndroidX library? in that case there's no `getView()`, so your only option would be creating a custom Preference class and get your view that way.

Comment: Yes I'm using androidx. I added `android:onClick="maleFunction"` to my `TextView` and now it's able to click only that textview and not the whole `Preference` ( added a `maleFunction()` in my `PreferencesFragment`). However it crashes when I click it: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method maleFunction(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView with id 'male'` any idea?

Comment: All good I added the function in the activity and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: huh, glad it worked, so the view binding thing works that easily but to implement it manually is so hard, Android always amazes me.

Comment: well, if you need more than just the onClick method, you can always try the custom preference class method.

Comment: You were right - had to extend it. Didn't know it was that simple, thanks!! Much more flexible now